# Ingnite automatically load data if persistent database is updated

Tags: database, caching, storage, ignite, persistent-connection

See I have one use-case, where My backend persistent DB is an **oracle**, and I m using ignite as cache, so I have already loaded some part of a column from persistent data, but here my question is if persistent data is updated, the same should be reflected into **ignite** cache automatically to perform some task on updated persistent data.
*Please respond, if is it possible or some way to handle this*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Ignite does not support a generic case of pulling real-time updates from RDBMS, because SQL do not have any generic mechanism for subscribing on updates.

GridGain, which is built upon Apache Ignite, offers a specific [paid integration with Oracle Golden Gate](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/integrations/oraclegg/gg-replication).

Comment: By using the JDBC connector can we achieve this, if possible.?

Comment: As I have told you, neither JDBC or SQL has update notifications. They only do queries, so it's not possible to reflect all updates immediately as they are done in RDBMS.